# How to insert iframe in wordpress using dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, iframe

I want to insert **iframe** in my **wordpress** website.

however i am unable to do so.

here is my code:

```html
<iframe id="eventListIframe" src="http://www.example.com/widgets/eventList_.php?id=781ea4dab64042de4fbdc6d9102ef0e7" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;" ></iframe><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/widgets/iframeResizer.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">iFrameResize({log:false,enablePublicMethods:true});</script>
```

when i check on my website , i get **iFrameResize({log:false,enablePublicMethods:true});** text as output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed one web page (the data visualization) inside a second web page (the organization's website), we use a simple HTML code known as **iframe**.

WordPress removes iframe html tags because of security reasons. Iframe shortcode is the replacement of the iframe html tag and accepts the same params as iframe html tag does. You may use iframe shortcode to embed content from YouTube, Vimeo, Google Maps or from any external page.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/

**If you want to go through other way - Code**

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20202/embed-iframe-or-html-page-into-dashboard-widget

Comment: Thank you @Rishi,I think you are beginner in wp.Please refer a `wordpress codex`